# Unable to stop the creation of backups to root by Vim/Emacs

Tags: unix, vim, path, backup

**Problem 1:** my Vim makes backups with the extension ~ to my root

I have the following line in my .vimrc

```
set backup backupdir=~/tmp/vim//,~/tmp//,.//,/var/tmp//,/tmp//$
```

However, I cannot see a root directory in the line.

**Why does my *Vim* make backups of my shell scripts** with the extension ~ to my root?

---

**Problem 2:** my Zsh run my shell scripts at login which I have in my PATH. For instance, my "replaceUp" shell-script started at my root at login. I keep it at ~/bin/shells/apps by default.

**Why does Zsh run shell scripts which are in my PATH  at login?**

Comment: What editor did you use to modify .zshrc?  At least one editor (emacs) automatically creates backups of modified files with ~ as a suffix.

Comment: @Nathan: I use mostly Vim. I use Emacs only in readig manuals. -- I have the following in my .vimrc: set backup backupdir=~/tmp/vim//,~/tmp//,.//,/var/tmp//,/tmp//$ . Perhaps, it is the reason for my strange backups.

Comment: When you say "root", do you mean your home directory or the file system root ("/")?

Comment: @glenn: I mean file system root "/". That is the problem. I do not understand why my backups go to my root, which I want to keep a "sacred heaven".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The files ending with ~ are swap files used by vim while editing files. You can try setting the `backupdir` and `directory` variables

```
set backupdir=~/tmp/vim//,~/tmp//,.//,/var/tmp//,/tmp//
set directory=~/tmp/vim//,~/tmp//,.//,/var/tmp//,/tmp//
```

Comment: Why do you write double slashes after directory names (does it mean something?) What does the $-sign do? I would just write "set backupdir=~/tmp/vim,~/tmp,.,/var/tmp,/tmp"

Comment: @hcs42: Thank you for pointing that out! The dollars caused me some unexpected problems.

Comment: See vim's help page for 'directory': For Unix and Win32, if a directory ends in two path separators "//" or "\\", the swap file name will be built from the complete path to the file with all path separators substituted to percent '%' signs. This will ensure file name uniqueness in the preserve directory.